# Python: Submitting different jobs to different CPUs

Tags: python

I have a fortran `atoms.out` file that performs some function. I am calling that fortran file from within python with:

```
values = subprocess.Popen(["./atoms.out", "./%s.klj" % test1, "./%s.out" % test1], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

I've looked at [Python PP](http://www.parallelpython.com/content/view/15/30/), but I dont think it is what I am looking for, as it uses n number of CPUs for a single job.

The calculations conducted by the fortran file are not independent and cannot be used with `python pp`

So my question is how can i submit a number of jobs to a number of different CPUs, say for example I have: 7 Files that I want to be run over 4 CPUs.

So each job is distributed as:

```
File1 -> CPU1
File2 -> CPU2
File3 -> CPU3
File4 -> CPU4
```

Then when a job has finished on a CPU it is replaces with the remaining 3 Files to run. Say `File1` is finished on `CPU1` it is replaced by `File5`, so the distribution of jobs would look like:

```
File5 -> CPU1
File2 -> CPU2
File3 -> CPU3
File4 -> CPU4
```

And so forth until it has finished running the fortran file on the 7 files.

Comment: Did you check the multiprocessing module of Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` class to create a thread pool consisting of (in your case) four threads. Submit the `subprocess.Popen` task to the pool using e.g. `pool.map`. Then, the four threads in Python will spawn one Fortran process each.

Comment: +1 Note that the `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` will default to creating the same number of processes as CPU core count, it's a nice default.